# Sentence structure - break it down?

Tags: sentence-structure

I'm watching the movie "Who am I - no system is safe".

The sentence

> Es ist kein Faden, der vorne einen Anfang und hinten ein Ende hat.

translates into English as

> There is nothing with a beginning at front and an end at the back.

But in the context of the plot, the subs reads:

> Every thing has a beginning and an end.

1) Which one is correct?

2) Can you please explain the sentence structure. What is the role of *der*, *kein*, ...?

Comment: Außer es ist eine Wurst, dann hat es natürlich nur zwei Enden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The sentence means

> **This is not a thread with a beginning in the front and an end at the back.**

(Hopefully I got it right, my English is not so awesome!)

Breaking down:

> Es ist **kein** Faden.
>
> *This is **not a** thread.*

And the subsentence:

> Er hat vorne einen Anfang und hinten ein Ende.
>
> *It has a beginning at the front and an end at the back.*

And now linked with *der* (*which*) with its literal German translation.

> Es ist kein Faden, **der** vorne einen Anfang und hinten ein Ende hat.
>
> *This is not a thread, **which** has a beginning at the front and an end at the back.*

Answer (score 3):

```
┏━━━━━━━MAIN CLAUSE━━━━━━━┓  ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━RELATIVE CLAUSE (subordinate clause)━━━━━━━━━━━┓
  Es ist {kein Faden}ᴺᴼᴹ  ,  der vorne {einen Anfang}ᴬᴷᴷ und hinten {ein Ende}ᴬᴷᴷ hat.
```

Literally: "It is no thread that has in the front a beginning and in the rear an ending."

This is a compound sentence with a relative clause separated with a comma (!) and introduced with `der` used as a **relative pronoun**.

In the main clause, `kein` is the negating indefinite pronoun used attributively of a noun (kein Faden = no thread) that governs the inflection of the indefinite pronoun: singular masculine. The noun phrase `kein Faden` is in the nominative case because it is the object of the verb `ist` (sein).

The relative clause describes the object noun `Faden`, therefore the relative pronoun `der`, referring back to 'Faden', is inflected in agreement with it: masculine singular, nominative.

The noun phrases `einen Anfang` and `ein Ende` are in the accusative case because they are objects of the verb `hat` (haben).